# At runtime, how do I list all Objective-C class methods for a given class?

Tags: objective-c

To list all instance methods for an Objective-C class, you'd use `NSClassFromString("UIView")` to get the class, then you'd call `class_copyMethodList` to get the list of methods.

But how do you obtain the class methods for that class, not the instance methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each Objective-C `@implementation` is represented at run time by an object, the “class object”. The class object manages the method dictionary for instance methods.

For example, for `UIView`, there is an `UIView` class object. When you call `NSClassFromString(@"UIView")` (or `[UIView class]` or `[UIView self]`), it returns the `UIView` class object. The `UIView` class object manages the method dictionary for `UIView` instance methods.

The `UIView` class object is itself an instance of another class, called the `UIView` metaclass. The `UIView` metaclass is represented by another class object, the `UIView` metaclass object. The `UIView` metaclass object manages the method dictionary for `UIView` class methods.

So, to get the class method list for `UIView`, you need to pass the `UIView` metaclass object to `class_copyMethodList`.

```
Class UIView_class = NSClassFromString(@"UIView");
Class UIView_metaclass = object_getClass(UIView_class);
unsigned int count;
Method *classMethods = class_copyMethodList(UIView_metaclass, &count);
```

Comment: Is `[UIView class]` equivalent to `object_getClass(UIView_class)`? I think I tried the former, but not the latter. Curious if there are any functional differences. E.g. does `[[[UIView alloc] class] class]` give the metaclass of UIView, or is `object_getClass` required to obtain it?

Comment: No. [Quoting Greg Parker](http://www.sealiesoftware.com/blog/archive/2009/04/14/objc_explain_Classes_and_metaclasses.html) (former maintainer of Apple's Objective-C runtime): “ For example, `[NSObject class]` is identical to `[NSObject self]`, even though in formal terms it ought to return the metaclass that `NSObject->isa` points to. The Objective-C language is a set of practical compromises; here it limits the class schema before it gets too, well, meta.”

Comment: To clarify, by ”No”, I meant `[UIView class]` is not equivalent to `object_getClass(UIView_class)`.

Comment: Thank you. It was highly confusing that the class of the class wasn’t the metaclass. object_getClass is apparently the way to get it, as you say. I wonder if there’s any way to do it in pure Objective-C... though I suppose C counts as “part of Objective-C”. On the other hand Swift might not have access to object_getClass by default.

Comment: Most if not all of the Objective-C runtime methods are available in Swift.

Comment: A better example is that you can’t use NSInvocation to access object_getClass, whereas you can for class. In practical terms that doesn’t matter much... except for my case, which is to expose Objective-C to JavaScript (V8, not JSCore). It feels a bit strange that it has to be a separate binding specifically for the metaclass when everything else is just an Objective-C method/property/ivar. Anyway, thanks again.